# Slow S3 -> EC2 transfer. Wrong code?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using this script with PHP5-CLI to download a file from Amazon S3 to an EC2 instance, but it's rather slow (1 minute for 160 MB, about 2 MB/s). Supposedly at least 10 MB/s should be possible. Am I doing something wrong in the code?

```
require 'aws-sdk/sdk.class.php';

$s3 = new AmazonS3(array(
        'key' => '********',
        'secret' => '******************'
));
$s3->get_object('mahbucket', 'filename.tar.gz', array('fileDownload' => 'downloaded.tar.gz'));
```

The bucket is in `eu-west-1` and the instance in `eu-west-1a`

([Cross posted to AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96221&tstart=0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script looks fine, but I ran into similar issues a while ago, which I wasn't abled to fix …

My new approach is using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) for the file transfer between S3 buckets and my EC2 instances. You just have to configure it once and then you're abled to trigger it via PHP. It's also more secure because you don't have to store your AWS credentials inside your script.

In my opinion the speed is okay:

```
user@mothership:~/s3# s3cmd put test.bin s3://data.example.com/test.bin

test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 1 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    16.39 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 2 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    15.55 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 3 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    16.18 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 4 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    17.32 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 5 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    18.87 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 6 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    16.58 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 7 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    16.29 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 8 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    16.95 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 9 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    15.33 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 10 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    17.01 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 11 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    15.36 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 12 of 13, 15MB]
 15728640 of 15728640   100% in    0s    16.56 MB/s  done
test.bin -> s3://data.example.com/test.bin  [part 13 of 13, 10MB]
 11256320 of 11256320   100% in    0s    14.15 MB/s  done

user@mothership:~/s3# s3cmd get s3://data.example.com/test.bin test.bin.new
s3://data.example.com/test.bin -> test.bin.new  [1 of 1]
 200000000 of 200000000   100% in   11s    16.20 MB/s  done
```

Maybe this article is interesting as well: [Network performance within Amazon EC2 and to Amazon S3](http://blog.rightscale.com/2007/10/28/network-performance-within-amazon-ec2-and-to-amazon-s3/)

Comment: Actually I just made this script to be able to use it from bash, so s3cmd would seem perfect for me, no PHP needed at all. I'll check it out.

Comment: I'm using s3cmd now and it's much faster, about 10 MB/s. Either it's just faster today, or the PHP SDK is slower (possibly CPU bound, since the instance is a small one), but whatever the reason, it appears this issue is resolved.